# How to write this query to join output of two queries

Tags: sql, psql

I have a table in which I/P file and O/P files are there
I have a query to find I/P file:

```
select sourceid 
from audittraillogentry 
where event ='67' and innodename like '%_collector';
```

The output is:

```
        sourceid        
------------------------
 ADZONE_20140203_135600
 ADZONE_20140202_165500
```

And the Output Query:

```
select  destinationid 
from audittraillogentry 
where event ='68' 
  and (outnodename like '%_distributer' or outnodename like '%_Arch');
```

The output is:

```
       destinationid       
---------------------------
 ADZONE_20140203_135600A
 ADZONE_20140203_135600A.Z
 ADZONE_20140202_165500A
 ADZONE_20140202_165500A.Z
```

As you can see there are two output per input file: ADZONE_20140203_135600 input file generates ADZONE_20140203_135600A and ADZONE_20140203_135600A.Z file

Now I want a final output like:

```
ADZONE_20140203_135600      |    ADZONE_20140203_135600A
ADZONE_20140203_135600      |    ADZONE_20140203_135600A.Z
ADZONE_20140202_165500      |    ADZONE_20140202_165500A
ADZONE_20140202_165500      |    ADZONE_20140202_165500A.Z
```

is it possible to do this?, if yes please help me in it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply join them using a LIKE:

```
select *
from
 (
   select sourceid 
   from audittraillogentry 
   where event ='67' and innodename like '%_collector'
 ) as t1
join
 (
   select  destinationid 
   from audittraillogentry 
   where event ='68' 
     and (outnodename like '%_distributer' or outnodename like '%_Arch')
 ) as t2
 on t2.destinationid like t1.sourceid || '%'
```